# Writing a query for figuring out non-existent parent IDs in SQL

Tags: sql, parent-child

I have a table (Table1) wherein some columns reference another table (Table2) by id. it looks something like this:

Table 1

```
ID   Column 1    Column 2    Column 3
 3         15          16           0
 4         19           0           0
 5         21          22          23
 6          0           0           0
 7         25          26           0
 8         27           0           0
```

Table 2

```
ID    String
15      data
16      data
19      data
21      data
```

etc.

I am trying to write a query that returns results like this:

```
Table2ID    Table1ID
      15           3
      16           3
      19           4
      21           5
      22           5
      23           5
      25           7
```

etc.

There is no reference to any sort of parent in Table 2, so I'm trying to figure out the best way to query this. Any help would be much obliged, as my SQL experience is about less than two weeks worth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use union (or union all) to combine the results of multiple queries.  There are some rules you must follow in order to do this.  First, each query must return the same number of columns.  Next, each column does not necessarily need to return the same data type, but you can get unexpected errors if they are different data types so you are MUCH better of if each query returns the same data type for each column.

Just to be clear, when you have multiple columns, each query should return the same data type for the first column, and each query should return the same data type for the second column, but the data types for the first column do not need to match the data type of the second column.

```
Select Column1 As Table2ID, ID As Table1ID From Table1
Union All
Select Column2, ID From Table1
Union All
Select Column3, ID From Table1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Table2ID,t1.ID
FROM Table2 t2
JOIN Table1 t1
   ON t2.Table1ID=t1.Col1 OR t2.Table1ID=t1.Col2 OR t2.Table1ID=t1.Col3
```